# What is the best tool or utility to create sitemap of a dynamic web based java application?

Tags: sitemap

We have a web based java/JSF/Spring application for which we want to create sitempas.xml and submit to search engines.
We want the process to be automated so that whenever new content is added , the sitempas are generated.
Is this the best options we have  ?
http://code.google.com/p/sitemapgen4j/

Comment: No responses ? Looks like not many Java users create sitemaps.

Comment: You should look into https://wutmap.com - they've got a simple sitemap generator offered via API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have finally gone as per google's suggestion and used the api's called redfin.sitemapgenerator

Answer (score 0):

Site's on which I've worked have had a limited set of defined section homepages, add those manually to the sitemap (unless your CMS has a list of those top-level pages):

```
/home
/section1
/section2
...
/sectionN
```

They also had content types: videos, articles, games, etc. You want to get a list of every single item -- from your CMS or, in my case, Solr indexes generated from CMS. This is a huge list of:

```
/article1
/article2
...
/articleN
/video1
/video2
...
/videoN
...etc!
```

The markup for sitemaps and sitemap indexes is [pretty simple XML](http://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.php).

Comment: I do not need manual solution

Comment: I've looked for automated solutions in the past; companies I've worked for have used automated solutions. We have found them insufficient. I've found that doing it manually is trivial, which is probably why it seems like you don't have a lot of options.

Answer (score 0):

If your content can be retrieved from a datasource, generating the sitemap through batchjobs (Spring Batch + sitemapgen4j) might work for you.

More information on this blog post:
http://www.jramoyo.com/2013/02/generating-sitemaps-using-spring-batch.html

Answer (score 0):

This website http://create-site-map.com/ uses sitemapgen4j. You can easily write a script that uses it to generate and download the sitemap automatically periodically.